# Best way to "wrap" an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I would like to represent matrix-like data in a suitable data-structure in Java. The dimensions of this matrix depend on user-input. One way would probably be to use a "magic" max-constant, and use a simple multidimensional array. But operations on the data depend heavily on the dimension, and I would like to avoid fixed arrays, since I'd always need to keep track of the used vs. maximal dimension. A more dynamic approach of course is to define something like

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>>> arr3d = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Element>>>();
```

I think this is unacceptably ugly. It might be better to define a custom data-structure, i.e. a one-dimensional ArrayList (or Vector), and then somehow wrap this i.e. map an access specified as [i,j,k] to some element of that single list. Is it possible to overwrite the operator []? How to do this efficiently? Is there some existing library or code I could lean on?

PS: I thought this might be a common problem, but despite best efforts I have not found an existing question. Apologies in advance if I missed some answer.

Comment: I still don't understand why not use arrays...

Comment: @m0skit0 Because you must declare statically their number of dimensions (i.e. `double[][]` vs `double[][][]`), and the op says that is to be determined at runtime. (I guess)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you create your own class to wrap that? It could contain your 3d list internally, but you expose only "user-friendly" methods to access and set elements.

And no, in Java it's not possible to overload []

A quick helper for that:

```
public class Cube<T> {
    private final List<List<List<T>>> elements = new ArrayList<List<List<T>>>();

    public T get(final int x, final int y, final int z) {
        if (elements.size() > x) {
            final List<List<T>> rowx = elements.get(x);
            if (rowx.size() > y) {
                final List<T> rowy = rowx.get(y);
                if (rowy.size() > z) {
                    return rowy.get(z);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can even do it in one line if you're not worried about readability:

```
public T get(final int x, final int y, final int z) {
    return (elements.size() > x && elements.get(x).size() > y && elements.get(x).get(y).size() > z ? elements.get(x).get(y).get(z) : null);
}
```

And you need put methods, that creates the rows (as ArrayList) when needed.

Answer (score 2):

It's not immediately clear from your question what you mean by the maximum dimension of the matrix.  Is it always 3-dimensional, or can it be N-dimensional based on the user's input?

Assuming it's 3 dimensional, is it regular?  Is every matrix [i,j], [i,k] and [j,k] the same as all others?

If so, you could conceivably model the structure as a single flat list, with two variables - one indicating the length of a row in a single level of the matrix, and another indicating the length of a grid in the 3d structure.  Integer division would give you the 3-d location in the structure:

given idx n, row length k and base size K:

`n/K` gives you the level and `(n%K)/k` gives you the row in that level. 
`((n%K))%k` should give you the index within the row, if I'm not mistaken.

Wrap this in a class which encloses that logic and you can treat it like a 3d structure from outside.

Answer (score 0):

What about an `ArrayList<Point[]>`? You can even thinking of implementing `AbstractList` to create your own list (even if you use `ArrayList` internally) and wrap the `Point` array creation...